# Using Javascript to access an html table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have php code below that is creating the html entry for the 2nd column of a table.

I am trying to get at the `$fldKF_Group` using javascript. I know how to find the cell and row using the command below but I can't figure out the part at the end where I mark it in bold.

```
 var GroupCurr = document.getElementById("Table_KaraokeSchedule").rows[RowCnt].cells[1].
```

can't figure out what to put here

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cell contents as bold using `.style.fontWeight = 'bold';`. See the working snippet below:

```js
const Table = document.getElementById("Table_KaraokeSchedule");
for (let i = 0; i < Table.rows.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < Table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
    Table.rows[i].cells[j].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="Table_KaraokeSchedule">
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```